# Create a combined Parse Query?

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I have a Parse activity class that has multiple different properties to it. One of the properties happens to hold pointers to photo objects. I am needing to create a query that will give me all of the photos, which are embedded inside activity objects that also need to be queried.

The method `– whereKey:matchesKey:inQuery:` seems like it should work, but for some reason it's not. Here is what I've tried:

```
PFQuery *activityQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"activityClass"];
[activityQuery whereKeyExists:@"photo"];

PFQuery *photoQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"photoClass"];
[photoQuery whereKey:@"objectId" matchesKey:@"photo" inQuery:statisticsQuery];
[photoQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {

    }
}];
```

The point is that I need to create a query that will return objects, which are imbedded inside of a different classes objects. When I ran the code above I just didn't get any results in the objects array. There should have definitely been something there as well if it worked properly.

Any idea on how I could accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include the photo in your first query:

```
PFQuery *activityQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"activityClass"];
[activityQuery whereKeyExists:@"photo"];
[activityQuery includeKey:@"photo"];    
[activityQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        // You now have the activityClass objects that has photos, 
        // and the photoClass objects have been fetched as well.
        // Iterate through the activityClass objects and get the photos from them
    }
}];
```

Comment: All that does is make sure that results are included that have a reference to an object at the given key. It doesn't return those objects directly.

Comment: Wrong, the whereKeyExists ensures that only activityClass objects that has a photo are included, and the includeKey returns the actual photoClass objects together with the activityClass objects. So only this 1 query is needed.

Comment: Holy crap! Thank you so much! I didn't realize that the `includeKey:` method fetched the data of the referenced object. That literally solved so many problems that I had. Thanks again!